# importing Excel sheet using maatweb to Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, excel, laravel-5.1, maatwebsite-excel

Am trying to learn how to import a basic excel sheet into laravel 5.1

```
vname        Vservice        vphone                 vmobile
test name    test  service   test number 123232     test  mobile 12344
```

I've made the following function

```
public function ImportVlist()
{
    Excel::load('/import.xlsx', function($reader)
    {
        $results = $reader->get();
        foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
            foreach ($value as $key => $value1) {
                Vlist::create([
                    'vname'=>$value1->vname,
                    'vservice' => $value1->vservice,
                    'vphone' => $value1->vphone,
                    'vmobile' => $value1->vmobile
                ]);
            }
        }
    })->get();
}
```

I've made a route

```
Route::get('/vlist/import' , 'VlistsController@ImportVlist');
```

and in index i've made the following link

```
<li><a href="{{ action('VlistsController@ImportVlist') }}"> <span>Import Suppliers </span></a></li>
```

but when i click i receive page not found beside the excel is not  imported into mysql db

Answer (score 0):

Action'ed routes should be defined as following:

```
Route::get('/vlist/import', array('as' => 'vlist.import', 'uses' => 'VlistsController@ImportVlist'));
```

Also, you can use `controller()` helper:

```
Route::controller('vlist', 'VlistsController', ['getImportVlist' => 'vlist.import']);
```

Then all methods within that controller with http-method prefixes will be binded to routes like:

```
public function getImportVlist()
{
    Excel::load('/import.xlsx', function($reader)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And can be referencet in views via route names:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('vlist.import') }}"> <span>Import Suppliers </span></a></li>
```

But personally I preffer pure `routes`:

```
Route::get('/vlist/import', ['uses' => 'VlistsController@ImportVlist', 'as' => 'vlist.import']);
```

And then you have no need to keep controllers and routes **and** views in synk:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('vlist.import') }}"> <span>Import Suppliers </span></a></li>
```

Pros:

1) routed name is more meaningfull.

2) renaming controller method requires only fix in `routes.php`.

3) it's becomes more easier to localise/customize route links/titles/breadcrumbs:

```
 <li><a href="{{ route('vlist.import') }}"> <span>@lang('vlist.import')</span></a></li>
```

**vlist.en.php**

```
<?php
    return [
        ...
        'import' => 'Import Suppliers',
        ...
    ];
```

**vlist.ru.php**

```
<?php
    return [
        ...
        'import' => 'Поставщики',
        ...
    ];
```

Comment: have you recompiled autoloader with artisan? `php artisan dump-autoload` or `php artisan clear-compiled` or smth like that...

Comment: composer  dump-autoload

Comment: well, then ensure following: 1) you accessing page via `http://yourdomain/vlist/import` 2) your `VlistsController` is placed in proper namespace (like `App\Http\Controllers`) both in controller implementation script and in `routes.php` 3) `vlist.import` route doesn't placed inside some prefixed group (`Route::group(['prefix' => '/some/path'],  function () { ... })`) or with midleware preventing from access 4) route to method is in routes list (`php artisan routes list` or smth) 5) controller method returns proper response (like `return view('vlist.import', [data => $data]);`)

Comment: ok i've changed the route to be vlist.create , now i receive vlist variable is not defined

Comment: when i make a route to vlist.create page it conflict with create function , when i make a route to vlist.import it says  page not  found  ,  idon't know exactly what to type in vlist.import and  how to route to it properly